# for every int x: x+1 > x .... is this always true?

Tags: c

I'm just starting to learn C at school, I'm trying to get a hold of the basic concepts.

Our homework has a question,

for every `int x: x+1 > x`

Determine whether true or false, give reasoning if true and counterexample if false.

I'm confused because we were taught that the type int is of 32-bits and basically that means the integer is in binary format. Is x+1 adding 1 to the decimal value of 1?

Comment: To answer this you need to understand that there are only a finite number of values that can be held in a variable of type `int`

Comment: Addition of `int` values is not defined in terms of binary or decimal representations. It's defined mathematically. It's up to the implementation to do the right things to the bits to produce the mathematically correct result. (And `int` is not necessarily 32 bits; it's required to be at least 16 bits, and it's commonly 32 bits these days, but it could be just about anything.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
x + 1 > x
```

is `1` for every `int` value except for value `INT_MAX` where `INT_MAX + 1` is an overflow and therefore `x + 1 > x` expression is undefined behavior for `x` value of `INT_MAX`.

This actually means a compiler has the right to optimize out the expression:

```
x + 1 > x
```

by

```
1
```

As `INT_MAX + 1` is undefined behavior, the compiler has the right to say that for this specific `>` expression `INT_MAX + 1` is `> INT_MAX`.

As the `x + 1 > x` expression is undefined behavior for `x == INT_MAX`, it is also not safe to assume `x + 1 > x` can be false (`0`).

Note that if `x` was declared as an `unsigned int` instead of an `int` the situation is completely different. `unsigned int` operands never overflow (they wrap around): `UINT_MAX + 1 == 0` and therefore `x + 1 > x` is `0` for `x == UINT_MAX` and `1` for all the other `x` values.

Modern compilers (like `gcc`) usually take the opportunity to optimize this expression and replace it with `1`.

For the record, there was some serious security issues with known server programs using code like:

```
 if (ptr + offset < ptr)
```

The code was meant to trigger a safety condition but the compiler would optimize out the `if` statement (by replacing the expression with `0`) and it allowed an attacker to gain privilege escalation in the server program (by opening the possibility of an exploitable buffer overflow if I remember correctly).

Comment: Is INT_MAX + 1 guaranteed to be INT_MIN?

Comment: @rogaos `INT_MAX + 1` invokes undefined behavior.  It *usually* results in `INT_MIN` but this is not guaranteed by any specification.

Comment: @rogaos Huh, what? If it overflows, then it invokes UB. It's not guaranteed to be anything, but in practice, it will most probably be `INT_MIN`.

Comment: UINT_MAX + 1 *is*, however, guaranteed to wrap around to 0

Comment: @H2CO3 thanks, I wan't clear. I edited my comment to reflect my real question. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @RyanHaining Does that mean that ouah's answer regarding optimization of `x + 1 > x` is only true when `x` is signed?  (If so that seems like an important piece of information that should be in the answer.)

Comment: I taken help from your answer to correct my answer, But I wont to delete my answer. Hope you have no objection, And many thanks for your answer.

Comment: @cdhowie Since the behavior for unsigned overflow is defined, the compiler could not optimize out the comparison unless it was absoluetly certian of the result.  If it optimized without knowing for sure, it'd be a violation of the standard.

Comment: @RyanHaining Thanks.  So it seems the answer regarding optimization is correct only when `x` is signed.

Comment: @cdhowie I added an edit to cover the use case of `x` being declared as an `unsigned int`.

Comment: A +1 answer is a +1 answer :)

Comment: Nice answer, it shows why this is a really really bad homework question on a beginner course (assuming the teacher didn't want to navigate right into the hell of UB, however it would be a nifty one at an advanced course!).

Answer (score 4):

Note for 32-bit number range is `[-2147483648, 2147483647]` that is equals to [-2<sup>31</sup>, 2<sup>31</sup> -1 ].

So for expression `x+1 > x` is true for `[-2147483648, 2147483646]`

But not for `2147483647` because adding to `2147483647` in 32-bit size number causes [bit overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) many implementations it makes `x + 1` to `-2147483648` But really behavior is 
Undefined in C standard.

So,

- `x + 1 > x`  True  for `x` in `[-2147483648, 2147483646]` only
- `x + 1 > x`  , for `x = 2147483647`  is Undefined value may be True or False depends on compiler. If a compiler calculates = `-2147483648` value will be False.

Comment: `iNT_MAX + 1` happens to yield `INT_MIN` in many implementations, but in fact the operation's behavior is not defined by the C standard. See ouah's answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson Not sure is it let me check?

Comment: ISO C section 6.5 paragraph 5.

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks Keith, I feel instead of delete I should correct my answer.

Comment: Up to you, but ouah's answer covers it pretty well.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes :) that is very nice answer, But I wont to delete because I given numerical range. May be it help-some one a bit more.

Comment: @KeithThompson May integer overflow cause an  SIGFPE signal and process terminate. I read some thing related to this here: [`FPE_INTOVF_TRAP - Integer overflow (impossible in a C program unless you enable overflow trapping in a hardware-specific)`](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_21.html#SEC336)

Comment: Since signed integer overflow is undefined behavior, it can do literally anything as far as the standard is concerned. Whether a particular implementation does this is another question, for which there are as many answers as there are C implementations.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I'd say there are relatively few.  Most implementations could in practice guarantee something more specific than Undefined Behavior: Such values may always wrap cleanly, always yield a number whose behavior is consistent with a Partially-Indeterminate Value whose lower bits are correct, AYANWBICW an unspecified value, AYANWBICW an indeterminate value, always recognizably trap, or always decide among the above in unspecified fashion.  Oftentimes, the cost of an implementation guaranteeing something more specific than UB would be far below the cost of a programmer avoiding UB...

Comment: ...on an implementation that doesn't.  Note that the second choice above would be sufficient for a compiler to assume `i+1 > i` is always true if Partially-Indeterminate Value is allowed to behave as through it has an arbitrary number of bits in addition to those specified (so the result of adding 1 to INT_MAX could behave like any integral number of any size, whose bottom 32 bits were 1000000000000000), but would still work with code that expects that multiplying any two `int16_t` and storing the result into a `uint16_t` will perform mod-65536 arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to hand you the answer, so I'll reply with a question that should get you on the right track.

What is `x + 1` when `x` is the largest possible value that can be stored in a 32-bit signed integer?  (2,147,483,647)

Comment: But this is not an answer. Should be a comment.

Comment: Would that cause an overflow? ... or will it wrap around to the negative value?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Perhaps, though I take a different approach to answering homework-related questions as the importance here is in the thought process and not the answer.  But if it makes you happier I will add an explicit answer.

Comment: @MattBall: Undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MattBall UB = undefined behavior.  The result could be anything.

Comment: Ah, yes, in C (the context of this question). I'm very used to Java.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. So the largest number that can be expressed is 2^31 - 1, and adding 1 to that is 2^31 which is -2^31, am I correct?

Comment: @gormandy Adding 1 to that results in undefined behavior; the result is not guaranteed to be any specific number.

Comment: FWIW, I'm a strong supporter of the notion of "strong hint as an answer to a homework question".

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, I am too. Much better option for actually learning the concepts!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, x + 1 adds to the decimal value of 1.

This will be true almost all of the time. But if you add 1 to INT_MAX (which is 2<sup>15</sup> - 1 or greater), you might flip the sign. Think about the decimal representation of `0111111` versus `11111111`. (Obviously not 32 bits, but the ideas hold.)

Look up two's complement if you're confused about why it flips. It's a pretty clever implementation of integers that makes addition easy.

EDIT: `INT_MAX + 1` is undefined behavior. Doesn't necessarily become `INT_MIN`. But since `x + 1` is not necessarily `> x` when `x == INT_MAX`, then the answer is clearly false!

Comment: Since the behavior of evaluating `INT_MAX + 1` is undefined, `INT_MAX + 1 > INT_MAX` could evaluate to true.

Comment: @KeithThompson meant to say not always. Edited to reflect this. Thanks!